# Swing JPanel 'viewport'

Tags: java, swing

When trying to paint a Graphics2D object, typically I've been translating to the center of a canvas and drawing from there. Below is an image of my gui in which the 'Generation of Artwork' panel holds 9 subpanels with some Graphics2D in them (the image displayed should be an oval but shows only a quarter due to my translating) but as you can see in the Biomorph 1 panel, the component that has been transferred over isn't being drawn in the 'viewport' of the panel. It can't be translated to the middle of the panel because the blue lines signify 0,0 and drawing is not shown in the negative region.

What is going on here?

[image: Image of problem]

```
public class BiomorphPanel extends JPanel{

PointCalc pc = new PointCalc();
DNAFactory d = new DNAFactory();
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private Graphics2D g2d;

public BiomorphPanel(){
    this.add(label);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.scale(0.1, 0.1);
    drawAll(g2d, 1, 1);
    this.g2d = g2d;
}

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {       
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     //scaling and translating to fit into mini panels in GUI
     g2.scale(0.15, 0.15);
    // g2.translate(-150.0, -100.0);
     super.paintComponent(g2);
     doDrawing(g2);
    }   

 public void drawAll(Graphics2D g2d, double x, double y){

     g2d.scale(x, y);
    // g2d.translate(-100, 0);

     //draw head
     Polygon hPoints = pc.getHeadPoints();
     g2d.drawPolygon(hPoints);  
 }

}



public class Gui extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel selectedBio1;
private JPanel selectedBio2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Gui frame = new Gui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Gui() {

    Control c = new Control();
    BiomorphPanel selected1 = null;
    BiomorphPanel selected2 = null;
    BMMouseListener ml = new BMMouseListener();

    setTitle("BIOMORPH GENERATOR");


    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("OPTIONS");


    JButton btnMutate = new JButton("MUTATE");


    JButton btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");


    JButton btnSaveDna = new JButton("SAVE DNA");


    JButton btnLoadDna = new JButton("LOAD DNA");


    JButton btnHelp = new JButton("HELP");


    JButton btnStartTracking = new JButton("START TRACKING");


    JButton btnStopTracking = new JButton("STOP TRACKING");


    Label label = new Label("Biomorph 1");


    Label label_1 = new Label("Biomorph 2");


    Label label_2 = new Label("Generation of Artwork");


    //bio1
    selectedBio1 = new JPanel();
    selectedBio1.setBounds(287, 32, 178, 189);
    //selectedBio1.
    Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    selectedBio1.setBorder(blackLine);
    contentPane.add(selectedBio1);

    //bio2
    selectedBio2 = new JPanel();
    selectedBio2.setBounds(287, 265, 178, 189);
    Border redLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
    selectedBio2.setBorder(redLine);
    contentPane.add(selectedBio2);

    //generation panel
    JPanel generationPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 3, 3));
    generationPanel.setBounds(10, 32, 258, 375);
    Border blueLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
    generationPanel.setBorder(blueLine);


    for (BiomorphPanel bp : c.getGeneration()){
        bp.setBorder(blueLine);
        bp.addMouseListener(ml);
        generationPanel.add(bp);
    }

    contentPane.add(generationPanel);

}

private class BMMouseListener implements MouseListener{

    private BiomorphPanel bp;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (selectedBio1.getComponentCount() == 0) {
            selectedBio1.add(e.getComponent());
            System.out.println("" + e.getComponent().toString());
            selectedBio1.repaint();
        }
    }

    public BiomorphPanel getBiomorphPanel(){
        return bp;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Care to show any code that demonstrates what you are doing?

Comment: `"What is going on here?"` -- I agree with @copeg: without code we'll be taking wild guesses at best. Some may hit the mark, but it may be hit or miss. Why not post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and allow us to answer well and with confidence?

Comment: Thank you for posting code, although it still is difficult figuring out what may be causing your error since we cannot compile nor run the posted code. Again, best if you could condense your problem into an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [sscce](http://sscce.org) so that we don't have to go through much code not directly related to your problem, but still would allow us to compile and run your code and experience your problem for ourselves.